# Unexpected type warning in `__new__` method for `int` subclass

Tags: python, subclassing

The following code:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs):
        x = x if isinstance(x, int) else 42
        
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs)
```

Results in a warning (in PyCharm): "`Expected type 'str | bytes | bytearray', got 'int' instead`" on `x` in the last line.

Why is this?

If I evaluate `super(Size, cls).__new__ == int.__new__`, the result is `True`. Wouldn't that expect an `int` as well?

Is there a better way to create a subclass of `int`, if I want to add behaviour when a value is first assigned or some value is cast to this type?

A concrete example of such a class would be a `class Size(int)` that could be instantiated as `Size(1024)` or `Size('1 KiB')`, with the same result.

Comment: In what line is this warning appearing?

Comment: As the text says, "on `x` in the last line"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of `int` with multiple args takes a string as the first param. It is roughly equivalent to

```
int(x:int = 0) -> int:
int(x:str, base: int = 10) -> int:
```

You are providing `__new__(cls, x, *args, **kwargs)`, so it is expecting that there should be a string as the first param.

So for this to not complain, drop the extra args:

```
class Foo(int):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        x = x if isinstance(x, int) else 42
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, x)


print(Foo(2))
print(Foo("2"))
```

```
2
42
```

Comment: That makes sense and answers my core question, however it raises another: doing so would make my subclass less capable than the superclass, since it would no longer accept the extra arguments. Is there a better way to resolve it that would allow my class to pass on any such additional arguments to the original? Do I need to check for both cases and call the method on the superclass accordingly? (that seems bad, since there might be more possibilities in future versions of `int`)

Comment: I suppose for the example I gave, that doesn't matter, since I already choose a different interpretation of a string passed, but more generally I think that follow-on question makes sense?

Comment: @Grismar I would only support the contracts which you expect/know about. If you want to handle the case more gracefully, use `typing.overload` to provide multiple contracts based on the provided arguments. In the actual implementation, you would want to examine the args and only apply translations which respect each case you have documented. Future changes to `int` would require you to add new overloads... which is a good thing! It would tell people to not use the new functionality as you haven't considered it yet.

Comment: You can check out how PyCharm annotates the `int` constructor in `<PyCharm base directory>\plugins\python-ce\helpers\typeshed\stdlib\builtins.pyi`, where you can see how it uses `@overload` to type hint the two signatures of `int`, which you are free to copy to your `int` subclass if you want it to be as capable as the superclass.